# Getting SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Expected '}' when trying to convert a string into JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

my code looks like this:

```
var str = "[{u'total': '54', u'value': '54', u'label': u'14 Sep'}, {u'total': '58', u'value': '4', u'label': u'15 Sep'}, {u'total': '65', u'value': '7', u'label': u'16 Sep'}]";
console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

In other words, I am trying to convert the string into a list of JSON objects using Js. I believe my string's structure is solid, however, I get this error in my console:

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Expected '}'
```

Can anyone help me fix this? Why do I get this error?

Comment: That's not valid JSON, as JSON can't have single quotes, hence the error

Comment: That string doesn't contain JSON so you cannot use `JSON.parse`. Seems like you somehow printed a Python dictionary. Convert the dictionary to JSON first and print that. *"... into a list of JSON objects ..."* [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Ok got it. How can I get around this though?

Comment: Convert the dictionary to JSON first. https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/json/

Comment: I believe that the only problem is that the last brackets is outside the string, as shown in the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot change this python dictionary, you can use a workaround:

```js
var str = "[{u'total': '54', u'value': '54', u'label': u'14 Sep'}, {u'total': '58', u'value': '4', u'label': u'15 Sep'}, {u'total': '65', u'value': '7', u'label': u'16 Sep'}]";

str = str.replace(/u?'(.+?)': u?'(.+?)'/g, '"$1":"$2"');

console.log(str);

console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```