# Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes - converting a string to a json object using Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to convert a string to JSON using python using the following code:

```
myStr = '[{u"total": "54", u"value": "54", u"label": u"16 Sep"}, {u"total": "58", u"value": "4", u"label": u"16 Sep"}, {u"total": "65", u"value": "7", u"label": u"16 Sep"}, {u"total": "65", u"value": "0", u"label": u"16 Sep"}]'

import json
json.loads(myStr)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

This makes no sense as every property has double quotes, not single ones. Any help?

Comment: You have lots of `u` characters prefixing the strings. These are invalid in JSON.

Comment: I believe it's the "u"... line 1 column 3 `'[{u"total":...`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the unicode qualifier from the string. `json.loads` assumes the property names are already in unicode.

Comment: How do I do this? Like is there a function that I can use on my string? Thanks.

Comment: You can do a regex to remove the `u` characters before each property name. Find a regex that will match  both `{u"` and `, u"` and replace them with `{"` and `, "` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
myStr = '[{"total": 54, "value": 54, "label": "u16 Sep"}, {"total": 58, "value": 4, "label": "u16 Sep"}, {"total": 65, "value": 7, "label":" u16 Sep"}, {"total": 65, "value": 0,"label": "u16 Sep"}]'
obj = json.loads(myStr)
print(repr(obj))
```

You try load incorrect JSON, you can check it [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/). I edit your json and it work.

[Here You find JSON Syntax rules](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Putting together the puzzle pieces from this question and [Getting SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Expected '}' when trying to convert a string into JSON using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534841/getting-syntaxerror-json-parse-error-expected-when-trying-to-convert-a-str), you want to do:

```
myStr = [{u"total": "54", u"value": "54", u"label": u"16 Sep"}, {u"total": "58", u"value": "4", u"label": u"16 Sep"}, {u"total": "65", u"value": "7", u"label": u"16 Sep"}, {u"total": "65", u"value": "0", u"label": u"16 Sep"}]

import json
print(json.dumps(myStr))
```

Then copy paste the outputted string into javascript.